# Best way for internationalization with Gatsby and Strapi

Tags: reactjs, graphql, internationalization, gatsby, strapi

In my company, we are building a static website using Gatsby framework and the Strapi headless CMS.

My question is how to deal with i18n?

First, I know that is a difficult question and there is not one answer, but different answers depending of the context. So, I will resume you my research, and I hope you will help me to close this topic. :)

**First** idea, the most easy one, let's search a plugin!

There is one : [gatsby-source-strapi-localized](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gatsby-source-strapi-localized)

Unfortunately, it is not maintained, so, I will not use it. :'(

Ok, **second** things, lets see what Strapi suggests!

Strapi does not have an i18n feature for now, it is planned for the end of 2020 on the [roadmap](https://portal.productboard.com/strapi/1-public-roadmap/c/19-content-internationalization-ce-ee-v4).

But there is a work around, using suffix at the end of the fields:
[medium article](https://medium.com/strapi/content-internationalization-with-strapi-507ef5869c15) (With the same idea, you can also suffix your Types directly)

So, now we got suffix on fields or types, let's go to the **third** part, Gatsby !

And it's a nightmare. XD

Actually, there is different solutions to solve that, but I did not find mine. :'(

I found this [article](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/blog/2020-07-28-introducing-gatsby-i18n-theme/), about the new i18n gatsby theme. I download the starter to try to understand how it works.
What I understand is that pages for blog are generated automatically in 2 different languages, thank to the **createPage** function. 2 mdx files are created to store the data and the **LocalizedLink** component are used for redirections.

It is interesting, but it does not fit my problem well. So, let's tell you what I thought:

***Spoiler alert ! :*** I am not familiar with the React packages for i18n, I just discover them this morning, it's why maybe I don't see the answer ^^'

First thing is "How to create the good url? " To do that, I have to choices :

1. Create 2 folders in my **page section**, one FR and one EN, it will be added in my URL (mySite.org/FR)
2. use **gatsby-plugin-i18n**, which allow you to create a index.fr.js and index.en.js to generate mySite.org/fr or mySite.org/en

After that, in each files, I can customize my query to ask the data in the good language:

```
allStrapiHomePage {
  edges {
    node {
      mainBanner {
        title_lang
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Or :

```
allStrapiHomePage_lang {
  edges {
    node {
      mainBanner {
        title
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For redirections, I can check the context to know in which page I am.

The things that I don't like, it's that I will have 2 files per pages, only for the query, the rest of the page is the same :/

So, the question is : *How can I generate 2 pages per page with the good URL and the good query ?* (you've got 2 hours è__é.... XD)

The **createPage** function allow you to pass variables in context, which could help me for the query. I can modify the path too, that can help me for the URL. But the folder **pages** are already processed by Gatsby... I can't modify the process.

Does anybody have an idea to clarify this topic? :)

Comment: We also have this issue. Will write here as soon as we solve it.

Comment: @IlyasAssainov any solution?

Comment: if you dont want to create several lang pages in /pages, you need to go the gatsby-node route and create the pages yourself. Thats what all the i18n plugins also do.

Answer (score 1):

I see that this topic is a little bit popular, and I never write the answer, let's fix that !

I don't know how it works with the new versions of strapi, but there is our solution for strapi 3.0.1 :

Each pages have two single types in strapi :

- Homepage
- Homepage_En
- About
- About_En
- ...

They have, of course, the same schema.

In my gatsby pages folder, we created two sub-folders :

- fr
- en

In each folder, you have all pages, but, the trick is : they are here only to get the correct data from strapi, let's see an example :

fr/about.js :

```js
import React from "react"
import { graphql } from "gatsby"
import _get from "lodash/get"
import AboutPage from "../../components/pageComponents/About.js"

export default function About({ data }) {
  const BannerAbout = _get(
    data,
    "allStrapiAbout.edges[0].node.Banner.BackgroundImage.childImageSharp.fluid"
  )
  const TitleBannerAbout = _get(
    data,
    "allStrapiAbout.edges[0].node.Banner.Title"
  )
  const DescriptionBannerAbout = _get(
    data,
    "allStrapiAbout.edges[0].node.Banner.Description"
  )

  return (
    <AboutPage
      BannerAbout={BannerAbout}
      TitleBannerAbout={TitleBannerAbout}
      DescriptionBannerAbout={DescriptionBannerAbout}
    />
  )
}

export const query = () => graphql`
  query {
    allStrapiAbout {
      edges {
        node {
          Banner {
            Title
            Description
            BackgroundImage {
              childImageSharp {
                fluid(maxWidth: 1920) {
                  ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid_withWebp_tracedSVG
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

And the same idea for the english part :

en/about.js :

```js
import React from "react"
import { graphql } from "gatsby"
import _get from "lodash/get"
import AboutPage from "../../components/pageComponents/About.js"

export default function About({ data }) {
  const BannerAbout = _get(
    data,
    "allStrapiAboutEn.edges[0].node.Banner.BackgroundImage.childImageSharp.fluid"
  )
  const TitleBannerAbout = _get(
    data,
    "allStrapiAboutEn.edges[0].node.Banner.Title"
  )
  const DescriptionBannerAbout = _get(
    data,
    "allStrapiAboutEn.edges[0].node.Banner.Description"
  )

  return (
    <AboutPage
      BannerAbout={BannerAbout}
      TitleBannerAbout={TitleBannerAbout}
      DescriptionBannerAbout={DescriptionBannerAbout}

    />
  )
}

export const query = () => graphql`
  query {
    allStrapiAboutEn {
      edges {
        node {
          Banner {
            Title
            Description
            BackgroundImage {
              childImageSharp {
                fluid(maxWidth: 1920) {
                  ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid_withWebp_tracedSVG
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

As you can see, they are calling the same React component , wich is a component for the full About page (with lots of sub-components of course), in the *components* folder.

So, after that, you just have to write your code once, with the correct props.

It's not perfect, but it works for me, and we don't have a duplication of the logical code :)

One more tips : be careful with your arrays of images, there are frequently the same between 2 languages, it could be interesting to use *collection types* for this rather than upload them twice.

If other people have ideas, don't hesitate to write your tips ;)

Have a good day everybody, don't worry, code happy !

Comment: I am about to try this pattern to handle languages, can you tell me how to switch language? Thanks

Comment: Hi @FarhanFarooq, 
What do you mean ? With the pattern, you will have https://myUrl.com/fr/ and https://myUrl.com/en/
Is it your question ?